# Convert String dict to dict python

Tags: python, json

I have a string below :-

`d = '"{""Source"":""Test Flow Action""}"'`

I need to convert it into a dict as :

`d = {"Source":"Test Flow Action"}`

I tried `ast.literal_eval`, `json.loads`, but was not able to succeed.

When I used `ast.literal_eval`, I am getting the O/P as below:

`{Source:Test Flow Action}`

But this is not in python.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Use the decoder for the encoder you used to create that string.

Comment: @Manuel Can you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
json.loads('"{""Source"":""Test Flow Action""}"'.replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}').replace('""', '"'))
```

Yields a dictionary looking like:

```py
{'Source': 'Test Flow Action'}
```

which is python, indeed.

Comment: Thanks. This is Superrr!!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying a little modified version of the same question just for knowledge purpose.

```
dt="{'a':1,'b':2}"
dict(dt.replace('}"','}').replace('{"','{'))
```

any way I can get dict type output `{'a':1,'b':2}`

Comment: I think I got the answer by using ```eval()``` like ```eval(dt)```